# Is this a good enough/correct way to show that a function is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

X is a vector space, $X = C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ and it's equipped with the supremum norm and $G:X\to X$

$G(f)(x) =\int\limits_0^xf(s)^mds$, for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm to show that G is differentiable at each element $f\in X$ and find the derivatives.

Candidate: $G'(f;r) = \underset{t\to 0}{lim} \frac{G(f+rt)(x)-G(f)}{t}=
\underset{t\to 0}{lim} \frac{\int\limits_0^x(f+rt)(s)^mds-\int\limits_0^xf(s)^mds}{t}=$

$ \underset{t\to 0}{lim} \frac{\int\limits_0^xrt(s)^mds}{t}=
\int\limits_0^xr(s)^mds = G(r)(x) = A(r)$
$

Now need to check linearity, boundedness and rate of convergence:

Linearity: Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$:

$A(r\alpha) = \int\limits_0^x\alpha r(s)^mds = \alpha \int\limits_0^x r(s)^mds=
\alpha A(r). $

$A(r_1+r_2) = \int\limits_0^x (r_1+r_2)(s)^mds = \int\limits_0^x r_1(s)^mds +
\int\limits_0^x r_2(s)^mds = A(r_1) + A(r_2)$

Boundedness: $|A(r)| = |\int\limits_0^xr(s)^mds|\leq||r||_{\infty}|x|
$ (Here I'm very uncertain).

And lastly, look at $\sigma(r) = G(y+r)-G(y)-A(r) =
\int\limits_0^x(y+r)(s)^m-y(s)^m-r(s)^mds = 0
$

Since everything is in order, G is differentiable with $G' =A$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Obviously wrong: $m\ne 1\implies (r_1+r_2)^m\ne r_1^m + r_2^m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is a composition of two functions:
$$P:X\longrightarrow X$$
$$P(f) = f^m$$
and
$$I:X\longrightarrow X$$
the primitive with initial value $0$.
We have:
$$
P(f+h) - P(f) = (f + h)^m - f^m = mf^{m-1}h + \hbox{higher order tems},
$$
so
$$DP(f):X\longrightarrow X$$
$$h\longmapsto mf^{m-1}h$$
And $I$ is obviously linear (and continuous), so $DI(f) = I$. By the chain rule:
$$DG(f) = D(I\circ P)(f) = DI(P(f))\circ DP(f) = I\circ DP(f),$$
so
$$DG(f)(h)(x) = \int_0^x m f^{m-1}(s)h(s)\,ds.$$